# Inherit CSS from preceding tr

Tags: html, css

I want to have my table rows alternating background color. But I have certain rows (class b) that are subrows of class a. Basically theyre indented to show that they below to the above row. I want those rows to be the same background color as their parent row while having the next "A" alternate back.

The table is being dynamically created so it has to be flexible.

I've tried every CSS selector I know but cant figure out how to pull down the "A" background to the "B's". Can someone tell me if this is even possible or will I have to restructure the HTML.

Im okay with using jQuery or javascript to solve this too.

SimpleHTML:

```
<table>
<tr class="a"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="a"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="b"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="a"><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr class="a"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="b"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="b"><td>asdf </td></tr>
<tr class="a"><td>asdf </td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.a:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.b td{
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLdo8nyx/1/

Comment: did you try this selector `.a:nth-of-type(even),  .b td `?

Comment: Maybe you should just change your html structure to fit the logic

Comment: @DanielA.White that just makes all of the "b"s grey when some of them may need to be white if their parent "a" is white.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can do this with your given structure. Sibling selectors can't select only up to a specific limit or element.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah thats what I was thinking. Any suggestions on a new structure? I was using divs but then I had to add a bunch of columns to the table and figured it would be easier to have everything line up with a table.

Comment: Keep your table but just put the `.b` into the `.a td` and make them display block.

Comment: @Brewal Put another TR in the tr so its `<tr class="a"><td>asdf </td>
<tr class="b"><td>asdf </td></tr></tr>` and make it display block?

Comment: That would be bad html. Put another table in the td then...